# MySQL return just the value without string parsing

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I made this code:

```
con.query("SELECT orgID FROM players WHERE scID = "+socialID+""), function (err, result) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        console.log(result)
```

It returns this:

```
[ RowDataPacket { orgID: null } ]
```

Is there any way to make it return just 'null' without having to convert it to a string and parsing it?

Comment: There is no need to convert into string or parse. `result` is an array containing a single object, with a single property `orgID`. You can access it with `result[0].orgID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result[0]` is just an object that happens to have been created with `RowDataPacket` as constructor, but you can access it like a plain object.

If you don't know the name of the field, then get the values of that object using `Object.values`, and if you expect only one, then access that value with index 0:

```
Object.values(result[0])[0]
```